# pysnmp prettyPrint() issue on hexadecimal number

Tags: python, snmp, pysnmp

I sent snmptrap using following command

> sudo snmptrap -v2c  -c public  '' .1.2.3.4.5.6.7.8.9  ifIndex
>   i 2 ifAdminStatus i 1 1.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.599.1.3.1.1.1.0  x
>   "0x34e2fd600a84"

I used prettyPrint() to format the output value in var binds. The problem is the output doesn't contain the leading zero. So the resulting output is something like

> so.org.dod.internet.private.enterprises 9.9.599.1.3.1.1.1.0 = 
>   0x34e2fd60a84

The result output has one 0 less than the original input. Is this a bug in prettyPrint or did I miss something here?

**Edit**

Here is my implementation. Inside this callback function

```
# Callback function for receiving notifications
def cbFun(snmpEngine, stateReference, contextEngineId, contextName,varBinds, cbCtx):
```

I have code block like this:

```
for name, val in varBinds:
        oid, label, suffix = MIBView.getNodeName(name)
        oidLabel = ".".join(map(str, label))
        oidSuffix = ".".join(map(str, suffix))
        oid_string = oid.prettyPrint()
        value = val.prettyPrint()
```

The portion `value = val.prettyPrint()` returns the hex value removing one 0 from two consecutive 0 pattern. So if print value using print value, I would get **0x34e2fd60a84**. But I would except to get **0x34e2fd600a84**.

Comment: It is not clear how pysnmp is involved in your situation. Some code would definitely help. On the other hand, leading 0 is a formatting property, it should not change the value in question.

Comment: Please see the updated question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That was a bug in pyasn1, and it was fixed in release 0.1.3 (current release is 0.1.9). You need to upgrade your pyasn1 or monkey-patch it if you can't upgrade for some reason.

Comment: After upgrading version to 0.1.9, its working as expected. Thank you